# Several functions needs to be called by only one function for radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, function, radio-button, choropleth

So, I'm making a map that can classify the data from each layer using one method. But now, I also want the user to be able to choose the method according to their wishes.

I want to create three radio buttons for the methods. After the user clicks one of the buttons, they can input the number of classes for the classification. The problem is that each method requires some function to perform the classification. So, I don't know how I can create those radio buttons that can call the appropriate function for each method.

This is the code for the buttons :

```
    <div class="method-container">
    <div class="method-title" title="classifications">Classification Methods
    </div>
    <input id="quant" name="metode" type="radio" onclick="quantile()">Quantile</input><br>
    <input id="equi" name="metode" type="radio" onclick="equidistant()">Equidistant</input><br>
    <input id="kme" name="metode" type="radio" onclick="kmeans()">K-Means</input><br>
```

Here are some of the functions for just one method :

```
function add_N(steps) {
        // some code here
            }
        }).addTo(map);
    }
    add_N(1);
    layerControl.addOverlay(n_layer, "N")

function add_P(steps) {
        // some code here
            }
        }).addTo(map);
    }
    add_P(1);
    layerControl.addOverlay(p_layer, "P")
```

This is as far as I get now :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z608J.png)

Like I said above, after the user clicks one of the methods, the user can change the number of the classes.

What I have in mind is that I have to create 3 functions :

```
function quantile() {
         // with the code for quantile method from above
       }
function equidistant() {
         // with the code for equidistant method from above
       }
function kmeans() {
         // with the code for k-means method from above
       }
```

I tried it but then the function add_N() and function add_P() couldn't work. What should I do? I read about nested function but I still don't understand how it works.

Comment: Please read your question, and ask yourself: "*with just this information could I possibly understand what this question is asking me?*" This is somewhat rhetorical, but I feel I need to make the point that we - or, certainly, *I* - can't work out what you're asking, or see enough of the context (the relevant "*[mcve]*" code) to begin to formulate a potential answer. Please, see the guidance on "*[ask]*," and then edit, and improve your question so that we might be able to help.

Comment: @DavidThomas I'm sorry, I'll rewrite my question to make it clearer

Comment: Thank you, that's much appreciated! Incidentally, if you expect that to take some time, you could close the question temporarily, edit while it's closed, and then reopen it (this avoids any interim down-votes/close-votes from accumulating while you're editing).

Comment: @DavidThomas no, thank you! I already edited my question. I hope I made it easier to read.